# Explaining the adjective endings in “Für seine guten Leistungen überraschte ihn die Mutter mit einem neuen Fahrrad”

Tags: declension, adjective-ending

I am still struggling sometimes to understand how it works with adjective endings. I already once asked a question about another expression and now I again found something I cannot explain. I don’t know which rule should I follow.

This is the sentence:

> Für seine guten Leistungen überraschte ihn die Mutter mit einem neuen Fahrrad

My problem regards specifically the first part of the sentence *Für sein**e** gut**en** Leistungen*. 
I thought that since there is the preposition für, which just goes with accusative, I would need to write *Für sein**en** gute**n** Leistungen*.

I add this picture, which is what I always follow when putting endings here and there. *Which declension* should my example follow? — *First* (prima) declension, *second* (seconda) or *third* (terza)?

- I guess that the first one does not fit, maybe in the second one or the third one.
  The fact that before *sein* there is the preposition *für* confuses me.
- It is second declension even though before sein there is *für*?
- Or is it the third one because there is actually no article (*der, die, das*) in *für sein[…] gut[…]* (= preposition, possessive adjektiv, adjective)

Can someone explain me why the endings are *-e* and then *-en*?

[image: Adjectives declination]

Comment: [Wiktionary](https://de.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/sein#Possessivpronomen): You are correct to expect accusative, which *is* "seine" for *Plural* Leistungen. And I hate to tell you that "that's just the way it is".

Comment: Possibly confusion with a male noun of _n_ declension in singular: _der Elefant_, _für seinen guten Elefanten_. (No, I couldn't come up with an example that makes sense.) However, it is _die Leistung_, and _Leistungen_ is its plural.

Comment: Maybe the key to clearing up the confusion here is that *seine* is not an adjective (but a possessive pronoun) and therefore does not follow adjective declension rules?

Comment: @E.V.: In your table, it is the second declension (*mein*, *dein*, *sein*), accusative, right-hand (plural) side: *meine ____en*. Fits.

Comment: ok I can see it :) 
So even though before there is a FÜR it doesn´t change the fact that it is second declension! 
THANKS!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is Accusative Plural of "die gute Leistung", which is "die guten Leistungen".

The sentence would then already make sense:

> Für die guten Leistungen überraschte ihn die Mutter mit einem neuen Fahrrad

But the sentence goes on to specify whose achievements: *His* achievements. So a possessive pronoun is being used, which is *seine* in this case (plural + accusative object *guten Leistungen*). The possessive pronoun is to be seen independent from the declension "Leistung", as it is not an adjective. It does, however, change to reflect number and case of the object. For example:

> Für sein schönes Haus (Acc. sing.)
>   Für seine guten Leistungen (Acc. pl.)
>   An seinem runden Geburtstag (Dat. sing.)
>   An seinen runden Geburtstagen (Dat. pl.)
>   etc.

So the real pattern *in this case* is

> Für seine [whatever, Accusative Pl.] überraschte ihn die Mutter mit einem neuen Fahrrad.

You could now replace `[whatever]` with

> ... guten Leistungen ...
>   ... schönen Augen ...
>   ... große Tapferkeit ...
>   ...

Comment: @chirlu Sorry, added the "possessive pronoun" part later without removing the genitive thing I wrote first... Edit my answer.

Comment: Is sein actually an adjective? ok possessive

Comment: I corrected this a 40 minutes ago. *sein* is of course a possessive pronoun.

Comment: @Thorsten Dittmar: I'm now wondering if you mean "now" where you wrote "not". However, while it is debatable whether *seen(e)* actually is an adjective, it certainly behaves like one in certain regards, and it does change depending on gender and number.

Comment: @chirlu I actually mean it is *not* an adjective. It's a possessive pronoun (as the term "pro **noun**" implies, it is a word that replaces a **noun**). Articles also change depending on gender and number, still they are not adjectives :-) What I mean is: "seine" is not an adjective to "Leistungen" as the OP thinks. If the sentence stated the person's name we wouldn't discuss this.

Comment: I always thought that mein sein ect..can be both possessive pronouns, when it is a word that replaces a noun (therefore the noun should not be there!), or it can be an adjective. That´s at least how it works in italian, I mistakenly thought it would be the same in German. 

La mia casa = Mein Haus (always speaking about the Italian example) (here mia=mein is considered adjective)
É mia!= Es ist mein (and here is a possessive pronoun!)

Comment: @E.V. I hope my Latin helps me here, but doesn't "La mia casa" translate into "Die meine Haus" (so actually "Das meine Haus")? This looks like an adjective alright, but in German, this construction doesn't exist. I may be mistaken here, so somebody correct me, but a pronoun remains a pronoun and never suddenly becomes an adjective in German. You *can* say "Das ist *mein* Haus", but here, *mein* again replaces the person/institution the house belongs to. "É mia" translates into "Das gehört mir". "Es ist mein Eis" or "Es sind meine Rollschuhe" shows that of course it changes its number.

Comment: When I say "la mia casa è grande" I would translate it as "mein Haus ist groß". So I guess I would always translate "La mia casa" into "Mein Haus".
In Italian before possessive adjectives (now we are clear about it :) comes an article (often, maybe even always). In German I never heard it. 
How do you use "Die meine Haus" and "Das meine Haus"? To me they sound completely wrong. It could be cuz I never saw or heard them.

Comment: "A pronoun remains a pronoun and never suddenly becomes an adjective in German"
This is a really interesting point for me. In Italian is true the exact opposite! 
-Quella casa (that house)=adjective
-Quella!(that on)=pronoun

They thought as this one point so ofter in school when we would study analisys grammar

Comment: @E.V. As I said "Das meine Haus" doesn't work in German. "Das grüne Haus", however, does, as "grün" is an adjective :-) "Quella casa" would translate into "dieses Haus", where "dieses" is called demonstrative pronoun (dieses, jenes, etc.). They can be used instead of the normal article (der, ein, die, eine, etc.) to put emphasis on something ("Ist das dieses Haus?", "Nein, es ist das [Haus] da drüben."). They behave like articles, though. Also, in German they are not adjectives :-D

Comment: @Thorsten Dittmar: When I wrote about _not_ possibly being _now_, I was referring to the sentence “You could not replace [whatever] with …”.

Comment: @chirlu - ooops, yes, that should actually be a *now* :-D

Comment: This seems to imply that "seine" is invariable, but dative would be "seinen guten Leistungen".

Comment: @CarstenSchultz I edited my answer to hopefully make this clearer.

Answer (score 2):

You are in the second declension. The head of your table tells you *which environment* the adjective is in. Your adjectives environment is:

- **Not** on its own (third declension), because there is a *für seine* before it.
- **Not** preceded by a definite article *first declension* — that would be e.g.

  > Für **die** guten Leistungen.
- It **is** the second declension, because of the *seine* (analogous to *meine*). (*Seine* is a possessive pronoun, and it actually reads *tutti gli articoli possessivi* in your table.)

Note that the entries of your table in the second declension’s column *alread include* the possessive pronoun (shown with *mein[…]*), so you can directly copy the pronoun’s declension from the way *mein[…]* is declensed. You can see that accusative plural requires *meine*, hence *seine*.

You **cannot** say that the *gute Leistungen* be independent of the *seine* — it would work in the plural, but **does not** in the singular with masculine and neuter nouns. Compare:

- > Für **die** gut**en** Ergebnisse […]
  > Für **seine** gut**en** Ergebnisse […]
- > Für **das** gut**e** Ergebnis […]
  > Für **sein** gut**es** Ergebnis […]